# How do I set up multiple tableviewcells in one tableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two TableViewCell's in the same TableViewController, and I'm wondering how to set up both of them. Specifically in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SignInTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SignInTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SignUpTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SignUpTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Here is an image in storyboard ( imgur.com/vCRGY6V ). I'm trying to set up these two cells. I've got the TableViewCells for both set up, but not the TableViewController where it sets up both. imgur.com/vCRGY6V

Comment: Huh? You can't have two different cells at the same index path. (Nor can you redeclare a variable like this.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know, just an example. What would I do to make this work?

Comment: For starters, explain more clearly what you're trying to do... maybe with a picture.

Comment: @nhgrif This is in storyboard. I'm trying to set up these two cells. I've got the TableViewCells for both set up, but not the TableViewController where it sets up both. http://imgur.com/vCRGY6V

Comment: Edit this into the question.

Comment: Have you attempted to insert a logical choice in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? Do you know what the differentiator is - that is - how will you establish a variable to determine which custom cell you would like to display?

Comment: @andrewbuilder I used what nhgrif said in an answer.

Comment: @user3398659 If you used something in a posted answer and it seems to be working, you should certainly mark it as the accepted answer.  It helps future viewers determine what solution was most helpful to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can return only one cell from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  You will need to use some logic to determine which type of cell to return.

For example:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    // instantiate and return one type of cell
} else {
    // instantiate and return the other type of cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-(int) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(int) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}


-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * cellIdentifierSignUp = @"SignUpTableViewCell" 
    static NSString * cellIdentifierSignIn = @"SignInTableViewCell" 
    UITableViewCell * cell;
        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifierSignUp];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row==1)
        {
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifierSignIn];
        }
    return cell;
}
```